# How to search through this list of arrays using a for loop. And check to see if it contains an element x

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this bit of code written here and I'm trying to search through all the numbers within the array to determine if it contains a number x, and then return a true or false boolean if it does. I am using a for loop to go through each element but I am having trouble determining how to properly check if the specific value x is within the array. The code I currently have is giving me a true or false if the array has the same index numbers as x. (Without using java.util.Arrays if possible)

```java
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
                if (x == array[i])
                    result = result;
                else 
                    result = !result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

- Assume it is not there so set result to false
- Once you find a value equal, then set result to true and
  break out of the loop.

```
boolean result = false;
for (int v : array) {
      if (x == v) {
            result = true;
            break;
      }
}
```

Or iterating with an index

```
boolean result = false;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (x == array[i]) {
            result = true;
            break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java streams gives an elegant solution:

```
result = Arrays.stream(array).anyMatch(v -> v == x);
```

I know this doesn't address fixing the OPs code, but I like to encourage the use of Java streams, as they have many advantages as code gets more sophisticated.

@WJS is right on in terms of giving you the two simplest, classic ways of addressing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    if (x == array[i])
        return true;
return false;
```

### Explanation

- if at any point in the loop the desired item is found, `return true;`
- if the end of the loop is reached, this means no item was found, so `return false;`